# What's the best way to present regression results in a conference?

Tags: presentation, tables

In many disciplines, regression results are a key finding that we use to present in conferences or seminars. I've seen many presentation slides full of numbers where in the end no auditor can identify a singe number.

What's the best way to present regression results (and other numeric tables) e.g. in seminars or conferences?

For example, what about mrkers for statistical significance instead of standard errors (or t statistics or p-values) and colors? Or should I prefer additional visualizations of coefficients?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about presenting statistical results - regressions are also used and presented in business, law etc. Would be on topic at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), where there are [69 questions on "presenting regression results"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=presenting+regression+results+is%3Aquestion) - consider looking through those, and possibly flagging this question for migration.

Comment: Have you seen the numbers for the tags? On CV, there are few, if any, questions on my tags. However, here the tags are widely used and my question precisely belongs to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid presenting tables but would focus on (margin)plots that tell a story (which, of course, is based on your hypothesis/es). Here are a few links/references that might get you started:

- [Using Graphs Instead of Tables in Political Science](http://www.princeton.edu/~jkastell/graphs.pdf)
- [Interpreting and Visualizing Regression Models Using Stata](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/interpreting-visualizing-regression-models/)
- [Graphische Darstellung regressionsanalytischer Ergebnisse](http://www.handbuch-datenanalyse.de/?q=inhaltsverzeichnis) (if you speak German) or [Graphical Display of Regression Results](http://www.uk.sagepub.com/books/Book238839/toc)